# Is there any algorithm that helps to solve an equation for a specific variable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two questions related to each other:
1 - Can all algebraic equations be solved for a specific variable?
For example, $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=5$ is an equation. If you solve for x, you'll get:
x=±$\sqrt{-y^2+6y-4}+2$.

It means no matter what y is, x will always be ±$\sqrt{-y^2+6y-4}+2$ if you replace y with a real number and solve equation.

Is it possible that an equation exists that we can't find x according to other variables generally? and we only should replace variables with numbers to find out what x is? 
2- Is there any algorithm or method to solve an equation for a variable ?
I mean how on earth did they understand for solving $ax^2+bx+c=0$ for x, they should add -c+$\frac{b^2}{4a^2}$ to both sides, and take square root of them? Is there any method for that? (for both equations and systems)

Comment: Short answers: no, and no, not in general.

Comment: what about the first question?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Comment: It took thousands of years to completely figure out how to solve $ax^2+bx+c = 0$. Even the notation that we're using today didn't appear until some 300-400 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

About the first equation, you have the equation of a circle with radius $\sqrt{5}$ and center $(2,3)$. That's enough information to work the equation  since it's not relevant and has infinitely many solutions. Interesting questions are about to find rational or integers solutions, which leads to the Algebraic theory of numbers.
About the second questions: it was answered by Evariste Galois (Abel-Ruffini Theorem). The equations on the form $P(x)=0$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial in one variable have a closed solution if and only if the polynomial has degree $\leq 4$. This is deeply connected with group theory and algebraic estructures. Take any book on Galois theory and study it to understand this "simple" result.

Comment: I don't think that Galois theory completely answers the problem that OP is asking. Elementary Galois theory is concerned about solutions of univariate polynomials in terms of radicals, but OP is asking about "finding $x$ in terms of other variables", implying a multi-variate setting, and not necessarily asking for solutions in radicals only. In that setting Elimination theory and Grobner bases give an algorithmic answer.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can't solve $yx^5-x-1=0 $  for x.
But note that even if you replace y with a number, still you won't be able to solve the equation algebraically and find an exact value. The question is: Is there any equation that is solvable if you replace all variables except x by any number, but you can't Generalize it and write x in terms of other variables?